# Comparing field names of two tables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have spent a few hours searching for a similar Problem to mine. though there are a few replies, i could not find any to the Point.

so basically, i have two tables. one is a Standard Access table (**table1**) and the other is a table imported from Excel (**table2**). now table2 has the field names of table 1 and also a few other extra fields that i dont Need. now i want Access to **compare** These two tables and copy into table 1 the contents of whichever fields that it can match from table 2.

i have tried `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, but the code does not seem to recognise this Expression.

can anyone suggest some ideas please!!! can give more Details if required.

Thanks a lot..

saran

Comment: Look up update query with join

Comment: Does the list of fields in the excel table change? If not, you do  not need any dynamic generation of sql.

Comment: You said `table2` has the `table1` fields plus a few more which do not exist in `table1` ... so if you want to know which fields they have in common, wouldn't those be just the `table1` fields?

Comment: @HansUp & Shadow... the aim is not to find the field columns.  Let me try to explain. Table1 has certain fields. These fields are empty, but they all have fixed field names. Now Table2 is what the user Uploads. This table will contain the exact field names of the table1 plus some extra fields. I want to insert into table1 the contents(records) of only the field names in common(table1 field names) from table2. i hope this gives a clearer Picture..

Comment: also table1 remains constant. table 2 changes everytime when the user Uploads a new table. so the new table2 gets added into table1 again.... so table1 keeps on growing,

Comment: So if `table1` contains 3 fields (`fld1`, `fld2`, and `fld3`), is this what you want to do? -> `INSERT INTO table1 (fld1, fld2, fld3) SELECT fld1, fld2, fld3 FROM table2`

Comment: @HansUp... this is exactly what i want to do... i have already tried with INSERT INTO.. the Problem with this is that... sometimes (fld2 or fld3) in table 2 may be empty or missing in such a case i want the code to copy the available fields and leave (fld2 & fld3) empty in table1. this is what i am not able to do..... and when such a Scenario happens the INSERT INTO Fails....

Comment: I don't understand why the `INSERT` fails when `table2.fld2` and/or `table2.fld3` is Null.  Seems to me the new `table1` row would have Null in both those fields.  What is the error message when the `INSERT` fails?

Comment: @HansUp....thats the funny part, the INSERT INTO Statement does not fail, it runs but copies nothing!!! There are values in the other fields but it does not copy anything because one or two fields are totally empty... should i add something in the intial code??.. maybe a case asking it to assume NULL value when the field is empty.. but i have no idea how to do it.... any ideas please??

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would give you the field names..  If static field names, id suggest importing to a table, derrived from your current import, and delete and  append rather importing each time, and use a join as suggested.

```
Dim a As ADODB.Connection

Set a = New ADODB.Connection

Dim r As ADODB.Recordset

Set a = CurrentProject.Connection

Set r = a.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns)
r.Filter = "[TABLE_NAME]='Your table name'"
```

or another way

```
r.open "Select * from table",a,1
loop r.fields
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan_Sav... Please help me with the Join Statement. I have tried using both Update and Insert Statements along with Inner join. Both are not working..  strSQL = UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.pnr = table2.pnr SET table1.risk = table2.risk.

Comment: and my SQL with INSERT INTO Statement is INSERT INTO table1 SELECT pnr, risk, reason, justification FROM table2 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.pnr = table2.pnr